# Android conditional import, preprocessor macro or alternative

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, preprocessor

I am asking this question as a product manager, not as a developer.

In one of our projects, we have several different flavours. For the sake of argument let's call them `free` and `withVideos`. The names are pretty self-explanatory.

Our project is divided into several modules. Let's call them `module_base` and `module_with_videos`. All flavours contain `module_base`. Some classes in `module_base` import classes from `module_with_videos` which are required only for `withVideos` flavour. However, even though those classes are not needed for our other flavours, we are struggling to understand how to exclude them. One of the classes which imports stuff from `module_with_videos` is our menu class. As you can imagine, there is a lot of shared logic between flavours, so we do not want to maintain two separate menu classes for different flavours.

In Swift or Objective-C (which are my main specialities) I would remove unneeded imports with the following preprocessor command:

```
import module_base
#if FLAVOR_WITH_VIDEOS
    import module_with_videos
#endif
```

It seems to me that this is not possible in Java. Could you recommend some other approach which could work?

Comment: "However, since we have some common classes (e.g. menu), we also need to import module_with_videos in it whenever we want to build withVideos flavour." -- that statement is not very clear. For example, what is "it" in the phrase "in it"? Also, in Java, an `import` points to a class, not a module, so it is unclear what you mean by "import" in this context. "module_with_videos contains some large assets" -- Java `import` statements are for classes, not assets.

Comment: "Unfortunately, this is not possible with Java!" -- Java has no concept of modules. Gradle and Android Studio do, but that is independent of Java. Java preprocessor statements would not help you with modules. You can conditionally load modules in Gradle with appropriate statements in `dependencies` (e.g., `fullImplementation project(":module_base")` would add the contents of `module_base` to the `full` flavor build process).

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for your question. I will forward it to our developer and will clarify my question. The problem is real, but I do accept that I may be using some wrong terminology given that my main background is Swift/Objective-C

Comment: there is number of external preprocessors for Java, for instance PostgresJDBC team uses [Java Comment Preprocessor](https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor) to tune import sections for different Java versions